# Sonar-runner import xml result from bullseye - taking one week

Tags: c++, performance, sonar-runner, bullseye

Would like to ask for your suggestions on why my sonar-runner has been running for almost 1 week, importing xml result outputed from Bullseye. Our c++ code base is rather large, a few millions of code at least.

I have tried to increase java heap size to eliminate the "ERROR - Unable to update semaphore org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException", by doing (export SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS="-Xmx3062m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m"). Also, my sonar-project.properties looks like this:

```
sonar.sources=./cplusplus
sonar.cxx.includeDirectories=../../../ThirdPartyTools,../../../shared_3rdParty,../../../NAG_Software,../../../Archive,cplusplus/framework/include,include/

sonar.exclusions= cplusplus/framework/include/boost/*,**/*.doc,**/*.docx,**/*.ipch

sonar.cxx.coverage.reportPath=testAllAppl.xml

sonar.language=c++
```

The testAllAppl.xml file contains all results from Bullseye. I am wondering what I can do to speed up the performance - It is a no go to do multithreading based on existing posts here.

Is it possible to put more in the exclusions, or am I including too much code (./include/ contains soft links to all boost libraries and our own libraries)? ***What else can I try out to speed up the performance?***

Thanks in advance for your kind sharing!